# Exception Tablename is not unique in c#

Tags: c#, exception, datatable, epplus

I am using Epplus to write a .xlsx file in C#. FirstIi write the data into a datatable and then copy the data table into the file using following code:

```
using (this.excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(this.destinationPath)))
{
    this.workBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
    this.excelWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets["Chat Clients"];
    this.excelWorksheet.Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable(this.existingFileTable, true, 
            OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None);
    this.excelWorksheet.Tables[0].ShowFilter = false;
    this.excelWorksheet.Cells[this.excelWorksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
    this.excelPackage.Save();
}
```

This throws exception:

> tablename is not unique

It works when I write to a new file. Problem exists when I try to write to an existing file. I changed the name of the data table appending date and time. Then it gave the exception:

> Table range collides with table Chat Clients 02/12/2013 13:21:52

What would be the reason for this and the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

```
**this.existingFileTable.TableName = "Chat Clients";**
```

Before the LoadFromDataTable:

```
this.excelWorksheet.Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable(this.existingFileTable, true, 
OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to delete the existing file before import the data table to excel.

Add this code before the `using` scope

```
if (File.Exists(this.destinationPath))
{
   File.Delete(this.destinationPath);
}
```

**EDIT**

Please ignore the first suggestion and then try the code below:

I think you have to add this line

```
this.excelPackage.Load(new FileStream(this.destinationPath, FileMode.Open));
```

And then your code should be:

```
using (this.excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(this.destinationPath)))
{
    this.excelPackage.Load(new FileStream(this.destinationPath, FileMode.Open));

    this.workBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
    this.excelWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets["Chat Clients"];
    this.excelWorksheet.Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable(this.existingFileTable, true, 
            OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None);
    this.excelWorksheet.Tables[0].ShowFilter = false;
    this.excelWorksheet.Cells[this.excelWorksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
    this.excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Absolutely correct! Thank you very much for pointing out. But then it is same as creating a new file. Can't I do it without deleting it? Or can u give me an explanation for this to cause. Thanx again to @Motomoto Pink.  Instead of this I can change the name by appending the present date. That way is more secured as we don't lose the old file.

Comment: By your code, it will try to create new work sheet names Chat Clients in the same file, so the tablename (sheetname) will duplicate. you have to handle by finding how to update data to the sheet instead. But if I was you and I need to keep the old file, I will create method to rename the existing file before create the new one.

Comment: What if i want to append data to the excel sheet what to do thn?